# Chainlink How to encode to bytes32 for results from external adapter?

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to set up a job for an external adapter. I get the results from the api call. It processes all the way up to the task parse. But when I try the task Ethabiencode I get this error:

encode_data ethabiencode
ETHABIEncode: while converting argument 'value' from  to bytes32: cannot convert decimal.Decimal to [32]uint8: bad input for task: bad input for task

abi: (bytes32 value)

data: { "value": $(multiply) }

Is the value from $(parse) there? or is it nil?

I am running v0.10.15

here's the job

```js
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Get > Bytes32"
contractAddress = "0x4dbDef7A9E395831FD2aD5754F6Bf81707017e28"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=bridge name="bet-ea" async="True" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": { \\"fixtureId\\": $(decode_cbor.fixtureId)}}"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" lax="True" path="result" data="$(fetch)"]
 
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bytes32 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0x4dbDef7A9E395831FD2aD5754F6Bf81707017e28" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
externalJobID = "19f6be23-b75c-4858-9e7a-be02679b83cc"
```

```js
{
  "outputs": [
    null
  ],
  "errors": [
    "task inputs: too many errors"
  ],
  "inputs": {
    "jobRun": {
      "logAddress": "0xd2de9f0bbe99c7100f8456548cddb33103122e57",
      "logBlockHash": "0x3ced7cf22e1b368b3c57580e66721dd632a216414c82caa26d6548b7a0aca842",
      "logBlockNumber": 5292158,
      "logData": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACvp9jgodQj3rZ71Dh9pqxgl+Vjjydtvwp78RTtc+VslKVNFOPNmD4kPnG/qlvDyrZ/tyqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA3gtrOnZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACvp9jgodQj3rZ71Dh9pqxgl+VjhJVWr/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABh8BvmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARaWZpeHR1cmVJZGY3MTA1ODAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
      "logTopics": [
        "0xd8d7ecc4800d25fa53ce0372f13a416d98907a7ef3d8d3bdd79cf4fe75529c65",
        "0x6231653236353232353131383431613562636666333864336333326337353663"
      ],
      "logTxHash": "0xf9c543ef3a4ca858ad7944af3b0970246f0002fcd76df5610b2be53b90a463ad",
      "meta": {
        "oracleRequest": {
          "callbackAddr": "0x0aFA7d8e0A1d423Deb67BD4387Da6ac6097E5638",
          "callbackFunctionId": "0x49556aff",
          "cancelExpiration": "1643125734",
          "data": "0x6966697874757265496466373130353830",
          "dataVersion": "1",
          "payment": "1000000000000000000",
          "requestId": "0xf276dbf0a7bf114ed73e56c94a54d14e3cd983e243e71bfaa5bc3cab67fb72a8",
          "requester": "0x0aFA7d8e0A1d423Deb67BD4387Da6ac6097E5638",
          "specId": "0x6231653236353232353131383431613562636666333864336333326337353663"
        }
      }
    },
    "jobSpec": {
      "databaseID": 36,
      "externalJobID": "b1e26522-5118-41a5-bcff-38d3c32c756c",
      "name": "Get > Bytes32"
    }
  },
  "taskRuns": [
    {
      "type": "ethtx",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:55.888153Z",
      "finishedAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:57.688118Z",
      "output": null,
      "error": "task inputs: too many errors",
      "dotId": "submit_tx",
      "status": "not_run"
    },
    {
      "type": "ethabidecodelog",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:55.8927Z",
      "finishedAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:55.8928Z",
      "output": "{"callbackAddr":"0x0afa7d8e0a1d423deb67bd4387da6ac6097e5638","callbackFunctionId":[73,85,106,255],"cancelExpiration":1643125734,"data":"aWZpeHR1cmVJZGY3MTA1ODA=","dataVersion":1,"payment":1000000000000000000,"requestId":[242,118,219,240,167,191,17,78,215,62,86,201,74,84,209,78,60,217,131,226,67,231,27,250,165,188,60,171,103,251,114,168],"requester":"0x0afa7d8e0a1d423deb67bd4387da6ac6097e5638","specId":[98,49,101,50,54,53,50,50,53,49,49,56,52,49,97,53,98,99,102,102,51,56,100,51,99,51,50,99,55,53,54,99]}",
      "error": null,
      "dotId": "decode_log",
      "status": "completed"
    },
    {
      "type": "cborparse",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:55.89282Z",
      "finishedAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:55.892849Z",
      "output": "{"fixtureId":"710580"}",
      "error": null,
      "dotId": "decode_cbor",
      "status": "completed"
    },
    {
      "type": "bridge",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:55.892858Z",
      "finishedAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:57.687947Z",
      "output": ""{\"jobRunID\":\"1\",\"data\":{\"winner\":7105801,\"result\":7105801},\"result\":7105801,\"statusCode\":200}"",
      "error": null,
      "dotId": "fetch",
      "status": "completed"
    },
    {
      "type": "jsonparse",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:57.68797Z",
      "finishedAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:57.687988Z",
      "output": "7105801",
      "error": null,
      "dotId": "parse",
      "status": "completed"
    },
    {
      "type": "ethabiencode",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:57.688014Z",
      "finishedAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:57.688071Z",
      "output": null,
      "error": "ETHABIEncode: while converting argument 'value' from <nil> to bytes32: cannot convert float64 to [32]uint8: bad input for task: bad input for task",
      "dotId": "encode_data",
      "status": "errored"
    },
    {
      "type": "ethabiencode",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:57.688093Z",
      "finishedAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:57.688096Z",
      "output": null,
      "error": "task inputs: too many errors",
      "dotId": "encode_tx",
      "status": "errored"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:55.886335Z",
  "finishedAt": "2022-01-25T15:43:57.688124Z",
  "pipelineSpec": {
    "id": 36,
    "jobID": 0,
    "dotDagSource": " decode_log [type="ethabidecodelog" abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)" data="$(jobRun.logData)" topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"] decode_cbor [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"] fetch [type=bridge name="bet-ea" requestData="{\"id\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \"data\": { \"fixtureId\": $(decode_cbor.fixtureId)}}"] parse [type="jsonparse" path="result" data="$(fetch)"] encode_data [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bytes32 value)" data="{ \"value\": $(parse) }"] encode_tx [type="ethabiencode" abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)" data="{\"requestId\": $(decode_log.requestId), \"payment\": $(decode_log.payment), \"callbackAddress\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \"callbackFunctionId\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \"expiration\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \"data\": $(encode_data)}" ] submit_tx [type="ethtx" to="0xD2DE9f0bBe99C7100f8456548cDDb33103122e57" data="$(encode_tx)"] decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx "
  },
  "id": "32",
  "jobId": "36",
  "status": "errored",
  "type": "Pipeline job run"
}
```

Comment: looks right to me. Can you post the JSON job output into your question as well? Each task should show what was returned before moving onto the next step. And would like to see what the parse and multiply tasks return

Comment: Hey Harry, thanks for your help! I edited the post to show the json error, please let me know what you think...the jsonparse task is outputing the correct number.